# Is my solution of a differential equation problem right?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, limits

I tried to solve the following problem but I feel that I must work a little more specially for the second limit. Please let me know if I need to do more.

Problem: Solve the following Cauchy problem.
$y'(x)=\frac{(y(x))^{2}}{1-(y(x))^{2}}\;\; and\;\; y(0)=1/2 .$

Compute the following limits

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 1/2-}y(x)\;\; and\;\; \lim\limits_{x\to 1/2-}y'(x).$$

Here is my solution.

At the first step, we have

$$\frac{1-y^{2}}{y^{2}}dy=dx\;\Rightarrow\; 1/y+y=-x-c.$$

Since 
$y(0)=1/2\;$
so
$\;c=-5/2.$

Now, we put 
$x=1/2\;$ and $\;c=-5/2\;$
then we have 
$y=1$
by the 
$y+1/y=-1/2+5/2.$

Since 
$f(x,y)=\frac{1}{y}+y+x-\frac{5}{2}=0$
is continuous at every point except 
$y\neq 0.$
We have 
$\lim\limits_{x\to 1/2-}y(x)=1.$

Since we have 
$y'(x)=\frac{(y(x))^{2}}{1-(y(x))^{2}},$
therefore, 
$\lim\limits_{x\to 1/2-}y'(x)=\infty.$

Edit after comments:

$$\frac{1}{y}+y+x-\frac{5}{2}=0 \Rightarrow y^{2}+(x-5/2)y+1=0 $$
$$\Rightarrow y=\dfrac{-(x-5/2)\pm\sqrt{(x-5/2)^{2}-4}}{2} $$
$$\Rightarrow \lim\limits_{x\to 1/2-}y(x)=1 $$
Also,
$$\Rightarrow \lim\limits_{x\to 1/2-}y'(x)=+\infty $$

Comment: Here is a link to a sketch of the graph of the solution: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/9s3js0j7vn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's correct, though you haven't really justified that the limit of $y'$ is $+\infty$ rather than $-\infty$.

Multiply your implicit solution by $y$, and you get a quadratic you can solve explicitly for $y$.

Comment: Dear Prof. Isreal,
Thanks a lot. 
I refined as above.